# Using autolayout to scale UIImageView to fill screen

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, autolayout

I am trying to get a UIImageView to fill the screen of any iPhone model but when I try to use autolayout to pin the image view to its container view, I don't have any success. I set the following constraints:

```
ImageView.top = Safe Area.top
ImageView.centerX = Safe Area.centerX
ImageView.trailing = Safe Area.trailing
ImageView.bottom = Safe Area.bottom
ImageView.leading = Safe Area.leading
```

After setting all of these constraints the image view still looks like this on the phone:

[image]

Comment: The image view is fine. It's the image view's `contentMode` you need to fix.

Comment: BTW - no need to set the `centerX` constraint if you have both `leading` and `trailing` set.

Comment: What contentMode should I use? I tried scale to fit, aspect fit, and aspect fill all with the same result.